# What are the comment only methods that decompiler returns?

Tags: java, android, bytecode

I was looking inside source codes of android apps for banks and I saw in most of them there were some methods which were doing nothing and inside them there were just some weird commented out codes.

look at this example:

```
/* Error */
  public final void b()
  {
    // Byte code:
    //   0: aload_0
    //   1: getfield 68 example/com/PackagePMB:y    Lc/y;
    //   4: ifnonnull +15 -> 19
    //   7: aload_0
    //   8: new 640 c/y
    //   11: dup
    //   12: aload_0
    //   13: invokespecial 643  c/y:<init>  (Lc/w;)V
    //   16: putfield 68    example/com/PackagePMB:y    Lc/y;
    //   19: getstatic 645  c/g:m   B
    //   22: ifeq +18 -> 40
    //   25: aload_0
    //   26: getfield 174   example/com/PackagePMB:p    Ljava/util/Stack;
    //   29: invokevirtual 648  java/util/Stack:size    ()I
    //   32: ifle +8 -> 40
    //   35: aload_0
    //   36: invokevirtual 457  example/com/PackagePMB:j    ()V
    //   39: return
    //   40: aload_0
    //   41: getfield 174   example/com/PackagePMB:p    Ljava/util/Stack;
    //   44: invokevirtual 651  java/util/Stack:removeAllElements   ()V
    //   47: aload_0
    //   48: getfield 176   example/com/PackagePMB:u    Lc/ag;
    //   51: aload_0
    //   52: getfield 558   example/com/PackagePMB:f    Lc/c;
    //   55: invokevirtual 190  c/ag:a  (Landroid/view/View;)V
    //   58: aload_0
    //   59: getfield 176   example/com/PackagePMB:u    Lc/ag;
    //   62: invokevirtual 192  c/ag:b  ()V
    //   65: new 653    c/p
    //   68: dup
    //   69: getstatic 61   example/com/PackagePMB:a    Lexample/com/PackagePMB;
    //   72: invokespecial 654  c/p:<init>  (Landroid/content/Context;)V
    //   75: astore_1
    //   76: aload_1
    //   77: invokevirtual 655  c/p:a   ()V
    //   80: aload_1
    //   81: invokevirtual 656  c/p:b   ()V
    //   84: aload_1
    //   85: invokevirtual 660  c/p:getReadableDatabase ()Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;
    //   88: astore 10
    //   90: aload 10
    //   92: ldc_w 662
    //   95: iconst_0
    //   96: anewarray 128  java/lang/String
    //   99: invokevirtual 668  android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase:rawQuery (Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/database/Cursor;
    //   102: astore 11
    //   104: aload 11
    //   106: invokeinterface 673 1 0
    //   111: ifle +55 -> 166
    //   114: aload_0
    //   115: new 282   java/lang/StringBuilder
    //   118: dup
    //   119: ldc_w 675
    //   122: invokespecial 285 java/lang/StringBuilder:<init>  (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    //   125: aload 11
    //   127: invokeinterface 673 1 0
    //   132: invokevirtual 289 java/lang/StringBuilder:append  (I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    //   135: ldc_w 677
    //   138: invokevirtual 294 java/lang/StringBuilder:append  (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    //   141: invokevirtual 297 java/lang/StringBuilder:toString    ()Ljava/lang/String;
    //   144: iconst_1
    //   145: invokestatic 683  android/widget/Toast:makeText   (Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)Landroid/widget/Toast;
    //   148: invokevirtual 686 android/widget/Toast:show   ()V
    //   151: iconst_0
    //   152: istore 12
    //   154: iload 12
    //   156: aload 11
    //   158: invokeinterface 673 1 0
    //   163: if_icmplt +75 -> 238
    //   166: aload 10
    //   168: invokevirtual 689 android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase:close    ()V
    //   171: aload_1
    //   172: invokevirtual 690 c/p:close   ()V
    //   175: new 653   c/p
    //   178: dup
    //   179: getstatic 61  example/com/PackagePMB:a    Lexample/com/PackagePMB;
    //   182: invokespecial 654 c/p:<init>  (Landroid/content/Context;)V
    //   185: astore 5
    //   187: aload 5
    //   189: invokevirtual 656 c/p:b   ()V
    //   192: aload 5
    //   194: invokevirtual 693 c/p:getWritableDatabase ()Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;
    //   197: astore 6
    //   199: aload 6
    //   201: ldc_w 695
    //   204: ldc_w 697
    //   207: iconst_0
    //   208: anewarray 128 java/lang/String
    //   211: invokevirtual 701 android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase:delete   (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)I
    //   214: pop
    //   215: aload 6
    //   217: invokevirtual 689 android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase:close    ()V
    //   220: aload 5
    //   222: invokevirtual 690 c/p:close   ()V
    //   225: return
    //   226: astore_2
    //   227: new 703   java/lang/Error
    //   230: dup
    //   231: ldc_w 705
    //   234: invokespecial 706 java/lang/Error:<init>  (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    //   237: athrow
    //   238: aload 11
    //   240: iload 12
    //   242: invokeinterface 709 2 0
    //   247: pop
    //   248: aload_0
    //   249: aload 11
    //   251: aload 11
    //   253: ldc_w 711
    //   256: invokeinterface 714 2 0
    //   261: invokeinterface 717 2 0
    //   266: aload 11
    //   268: aload 11
    //   270: ldc_w 719
    //   273: invokeinterface 714 2 0
    //   278: invokeinterface 717 2 0
    //   283: iconst_0
    //   284: invokestatic 616  java/lang/Boolean:valueOf   (Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;
    //   287: invokespecial 618 example/com/PackagePMB:a    (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Boolean;)V
    //   290: iinc 12 1
    //   293: goto -139 -> 154
    //   296: astore 4
    //   298: aload_1
    //   299: invokevirtual 690 c/p:close   ()V
    //   302: goto -127 -> 175
    //   305: astore_3
    //   306: aload_1
    //   307: invokevirtual 690 c/p:close   ()V
    //   310: aload_3
    //   311: athrow
    //   312: astore 8
    //   314: aload 6
    //   316: invokevirtual 689 android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase:close    ()V
    //   319: aload 5
    //   321: invokevirtual 690 c/p:close   ()V
    //   324: return
    //   325: astore 7
    //   327: aload 6
    //   329: invokevirtual 689 android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase:close    ()V
    //   332: aload 5
    //   334: invokevirtual 690 c/p:close   ()V
    //   337: aload 7
    //   339: athrow
    // Local variable table:
    //   start  length  slot    name    signature
    //   0  340 0   this    ParsianPMB
    //   75 232 1   localp1 c.p
    //   226    1   2   localIOException    IOException
    //   305    6   3   localObject1    Object
    //   296    1   4   localSQLException1  android.database.SQLException
    //   185    148 5   localp2 c.p
    //   197    131 6   localSQLiteDatabase1    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
    //   325    13  7   localObject2    Object
    //   312    1   8   localSQLException2  android.database.SQLException
    //   88 79  10  localSQLiteDatabase2    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
    //   102    167 11  localCursor android.database.Cursor
    //   152    139 12  i1  int
    // Exception table:
    //   from   to  target  type
    //   76 80  226 java/io/IOException
    //   80 151 296 android/database/SQLException
    //   154    166 296 android/database/SQLException
    //   166    171 296 android/database/SQLException
    //   238    290 296 android/database/SQLException
    //   80 151 305 finally
    //   154    166 305 finally
    //   166    171 305 finally
    //   238    290 305 finally
    //   199    215 312 android/database/SQLException
    //   199    215 325 finally
  }
```

What are these? why these comments were not skipped by the compiler?
because I extracted this from an apk file, and classes.dex is a compiled file, so there should not be any comments inside it, because the compiler skips them. but in this case it didn't and they are there as a main code!

does anyone have any idea about these kind of methods?

this method doesn't get anything ,doesn't return anything and doesn't do anything!

if this is an error by decompiler that couldn't decompile this method, then how can I do the same thing to my own methods so that decompilers can't decompile them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are these?

A dump of the original byte code.

> why these comments were not skipped by the compiler?

Most likely because the decompiler couldn't decode the byte code into Java.

> because I extracted this from an apk file, and classes.dex is a compiled file, so there should not be any comments inside it, because the compiler skips them. but in this case it didn't and they are there as a main code!

These are not comments from the original source.  As you say such comments are not in the byte code.

> does anyone have any idea about these kind of methods?

Yes, the people who developed the code.  The method called `b()` is more likely obfuscated to make it harder to crack.

> this method doesn't get anything ,doesn't return anything and doesn't do anything!

I am sure the byte code does something.

> if this is an error by decompiler that couldn't decompile this method, then how can I do the same thing to my own methods so that decompilers can't decompile them?

Use an obfuscater.

Comment: Thanks! a well formed complete answer!